# Any possible way to programmatically save to another folder other than the designated downloads folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, save

I'm developing a ASP.NET Web application in which a table is converted to an excel spreadsheet. I would like to give the option to the user to save somewhere else than the downloads section. I realize that is a good likelihood that this is prohibited, but maybe there is some sort of class/mechanism facilitated by ASP.net framework.

Here is my current code:

```
protected void saveDataButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog browser = new SaveFileDialog();
        string fileName;

        if (browser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = browser.FileName;
        }
        else
            return;

       DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["tableData"];


       HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
       context.Response.Clear();

       context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
       context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".csv");



       foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
       {
            context.Response.Write(column.ColumnName + ";");
       }
       context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
       foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
       {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
            {
                context.Response.Write(row[i].ToString().Replace(";", string.Empty) + ";");
            }
            context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
       }

       context.Response.End();
    }
```

I know the way I'm using fileName is wrong in this context, as fileName is actually storing file path + file name in my code. Any way to specify a file path?

The only other solution I can think of is if I created the some sort of file on the page and had them right click + save as. Is this a bad alternative? Are there others?

Comment: Windows application or ASP.Net Web Forms application, looks like web to me?

Comment: Are you really using SaveFileDialog in ASP.NET application!?

Comment: Peri: Lol not anymore. Doesn't make much sense.
/embarassment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The web application doesn't know anything about the local file system.  (Indeed, aside from the `content-disposition` header, the HTTP protocol doesn't even really know what a "file" is.)

What you're doing (aside from having the full path in the `content-disposition` header) is correct.  The standard way to send a file to a web client is to set that header and write the file content to the output.  What happens on the client-side is entirely up to the web browser.  If the user's web browser is set to automatically save downloads to a specific folder without prompting then you can't change that from the server.

Answer (score 1):

no, where the file is saved on the user's computer is dictated by the web browser, it has nothing to do with the web server.  think about it, you don't know what operating system a site visitor is running, let alone some arbitrary path you specify on the server.